# ¿Python 3 grafica mal una función?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

Saludos.
Estaba graficando una función cuadrática en Jupyter con kernel python 3 con el siguiente código:

```
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.abc import t
%matplotlib inline
eq=-16*(t**2)+20*t
plot(eq,t,xlim=(-1,2),ylim=(-1,7))
```

pero me aparece un gráfico raro:

[image: grafico]

La prábola parece estar bien pero la recta está de más, ¿alguien de ustedes sabe qué ocurre y como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, lo que devuelve ese código es correcto si tomamos en cuenta que le estás pidiendo las gráficas de `-16*(t**2)+20*t` y `t`, es decir dos expresiones diferentes, donde la segunda corresponde a la recta que *está de más*.

Recordar que la sintaxis más general de la función plot de SymPy, es:

```
plot(expr, range, **kwargs)
```

Donde `expr` puede ser una o más expresiones simbólicas a graficar.

En tu caso bastaría con que indicaras que sólo te interesa graficar la expresión guardada en `eq`, es decir:

```
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.abc import t
%matplotlib inline
eq=-16*(t**2)+20*t
plot(eq, xlim=(-1,2), ylim=(-1,7))
```